# Why am I receiving the error "Photos for the iCloud account [username] cannot be accessed"?

Tags: icloud, error, photo-stream

I'm receiving this error message periodically:

[image: Dialog box]

> Photos for the iCloud account "name@email.com" cannot be accessed. Review your account information in System Preferences.

Photo Stream is enabled on my iPhone, and the Photo Stream in iPhoto 9.4.2 is updating absolutely fine. iCloud in System Preferences allows me to manage backups, buy more storage **and** change Photo Stream options with no errors.

This feels like an OS X bug?

Comment: The next time this happens, you could verify the date and time zone are correct to within 5 seconds of Internet time servers and just reboot your Mac. It seems like a server error to me...